# Java custom Exception error unreported exception

Tags: java, exception, junit

Hi I'm having some issue while running junit tests on exception raising functions,

I have a custom made exception :

```
package rental;
public class UnknownVehicleException extends Exception{
    public UnknownVehicleException(){
      System.out.println("Vehicule not found in agency");
    }
}
```

Here are the basis of the RentalAgency class :

```
public class RentalAgency {
    // vehicles of this agency
    private List<Vehicle> theVehicles;

    // maps client and rented vehicle (at most one vehicle by client)
    private Map<Client,Vehicle> rentedVehicles;

    public RentalAgency(List<Vehicle> theVehicles, Map<Client,Vehicle> rentedVehicles) {
      this.theVehicles = theVehicles;
      this.rentedVehicles = rentedVehicles;
    }
```

and this function, supposed to throw this exception on certain cases :

```
/** client rents a vehicle
    * @param client the renter
    * @param v the rented vehicle
    * @return the daily rental price
    * @exception UnknownVehicleException   if v is not a vehicle of this agency
    * @exception IllegalStateException if v is already rented or client rents already another vehicle
    */
    public float rentVehicle(Client client, Vehicle v) throws UnknownVehicleException, IllegalStateException {
      if(! this.theVehicles.contains(v)){
        throw new UnknownVehicleException();
      }
      if(this.hasRentedAVehicle(client) || this.isRented(v)){
        throw new IllegalStateException("Client is already renting a vehicle or the vehicle is already being rented");
      }
      else{
        this.rentedVehicles.put(client, v);
        return v.getDailyPrice();
      }
    }
```

So now with all of these, I'm trying to run this test :

```
@Test (expected = UnknownVehicleException.class)
public void testRentVehicleIfVehicleNotInAgency(){
  this.renault.rentVehicle(this.client1, this.clio);
}
```

which gives me

> unreported exception UnknownVehicleException; must be caught or
>   declared to be thrown

and I can't figure out where did I messed up

Any help appreciated and feel free to ask for more details on my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your test method doesn't throw or catch the exception. You expect the exception but don't actually throw it.

```
@Test (expected = UnknownVehicleException.class)
public void testRentVehicleIfVehicleNotInAgency() throws UnknownVehicleException {
    this.renault.rentVehicle(this.client1, this.clio);
}
```

Comment: That was the problem indeed, thanks for the help ! :)